# Can you have a win32 program that consists solely of a tray (notification) icon?

Tags: windows, winapi, trayicon

I have a program that literally consists of a tray icon. No GUI is needed. However, when writing the win32 code, is it necessary to still initialize a hWnd object to be associated with the tray icon?

For instance, it is normal to have a the NOTIFYICONDATA hWnd field point to the window's handle. Like

```
nid.hWnd = hwnd;
```

Essentially, will my icon be able to still receive messages if i set

```
nid.hwnd = NULL;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How would you receive messages without a window?

Yes you need a window associated with the tray icon.

Comment: So I must create a window, associate it and hide it?

Comment: Create the window without `WS_VISIBLE`, and it won't be visible to begin with (no "hiding" necessary). Message-only windows are very common.

Comment: You can also have [message-only Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only), but I'm not sure if they work correctly with notify icons.

Comment: Well it appears Message only windows do not "receive broadcast messages". For instance, if the task bar crashes and resets, I don't think I would get the `wm_taskbarcreated` message. @MatteoItalia

Comment: Yea I should not have used that wording. I just meant a non-visible window meant only for receiving messages.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* create a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#message_only) by specifying `HWND_MESSAGE` creating the window. However, message-only windows do not receive broadcast messages and you would miss out on the `TaskbarCreated` message. This message tells your application that `explorer.exe` has restarted and that your application needs to re-add its notification icons. Rather important. So create a window that never becomes visible: **never** call [`ShowWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx).